# Загрузка изображения на сервер

Tags: php, android, сервер

Здравствуйте, нужно реализовать:

1. Выбор изображения из галереи
2. Загрузка на сервер

Можно ли загружать сразу в папку без скриптов? Или же надо писать код на php, чтобы принимал файл и сохранял его? Как это всё можно реализовать или где можно об этом почитать где каждый шаг очень хорошо описан? Перерыл почти весь интернет, встречаются коды, но они не работают.